# Como hacer consulta con 2 rangos entre 2 rangos de fechas del producto

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlite3

Buenas tardes usando Sqlite3 en Python
Tengo una lista de productos que tienen FECHA_INGRESO al almacén y FECHA_SALIDA al almacén. Cómo podría hacer una consulta para saber que producto estuvieron entre 2 rangos de fechas y que me seleccione todo los productos que se encontraron aunque sea un día en el almacen en ese rango de fechas.
Ejemplo:
Entre el 2019-01-15 al 2019-02-10 que productos se encontraron en ese rango de fechas aunque sea un día en el almacén, pasando como variables sus FECHA_INGRESO y FECHA_SALIDA

Algo así:
SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE RANGE(FECHA_FABRICACION - FECHA_RECOJO) AND RANGE(2019-01-15 - 2019-02-10) tengan un valor en común

Muchas gracias

Comment: Conoces la funcion between? Va muy bien para recoger valores poniendo como condición que un valor esté entre X e Y. Te dejo un enlace a la documentación: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp

Comment: Edita tu pregunta, muestra la estructura de tu tabla o tablas e indica lo que quieres obtener. A mi lo que me confunde de tu pregunta es "con dos rangos entre dos rangos de fechas". En tu consulta pones fecha_fabricacion, esa es la fecha de ingreso?

Answer (score 2):

SQLite requiere que las fechas estén formateadas así `YYYY-MM-DD` y pueden ser usadas con la función `between`, por la tanto tu consulta debería quedar algo así.

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE fecha_fabricacion BETWEEN "2019-01-15" AND "2019-02-10" and fecha_recojo BETWEEN "2019-01-15" AND "2019-02-10";
```

Esa consulta te regresará todas los registros que tengan ambas fechas (`fecha_fabricación` y `fecha_recojo`) dentro del rango de fechas dado (`2019-01-15` y `2019-02-10`).

Comment: Muchas gracias... lo probaré en la noche

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo pude resolver pero muchas gracias por sus consejos, el problema se resolvía viendo el problema como CONJUNTOS y buscando las 4 INTERSECCIONES

```
    SELECT B.ID, *
    FROM A, B
    where
    A.nro_desde between B.nro_desde and B.nro_hasta
    or
    A.nro_hasta between B.nro_desde and B.nro_hasta
    or
    B.nro_desde between A.nro_desde and A.nro_hasta
    or
    B.nro_hasta between A.nro_desde and A.nro_hasta
```

En stackoverflow esta mejor explicado con el siguiente tema:

> ¿Como verificar si dos intervalos de datos tienen elementos compartidos?